# bash: ./WorldOfGoo.bin: permission denied

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions

I tried to launch World of Goo from the terminal (`./WorldOfGoo.bin`), but somehow I couldn't launch it.

It displays the following error:

```
bash: ./WorldOfGoo.bin: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Make the file `WorldOfGoo.bin` executable first, using the following command in terminal:

```
chmod +x WorldOfGoo.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to insufficient permission.

If you are not comfortable with terminal you can also change permissions manually for your file(s).

- Right click on your file, then from the pop up menu choose **Properties** then tick the box **Allow executing file as program**

[image: Properties dialog]